C# reflection get method with no parameters
I have this code:
MethodInfo method = typeof(AppDbContext)
     .GetMethod(nameof(AppDbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

There are two methods named Set in DbContext, Set<>() and Set<>(string name) the problem is, there is ambiguity with this code.
So how do I get the method with no parameters?

You should've specified your .NET version because there is a better overload referenced in the answer by @KhanhStitsel but that does not exist below .NET 6.
Try this instead: MethodInfo method = typeof(AppDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(AppDbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, new Type[]{}, null);

Why are you using such code? That's a very strong smell. You don't need reflection with EF Core, especially for DbContext.Set<>. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a multi-entity Unit-of-Work which of course needs to know the entities it works with. When you specify a DbSet property or call Set<T> you're actually initializing the property metadata. Using .Set<T>() instead of a property delays initialization until the first use which is not desirable in a web application. The DbContext and DbSet types are already as generic as they need to be

You don't have to use the AppDbContext generated by your project template either, although you can edit it to suit your needs. You can have as many DbContext-derived classes as you need in a project.

For such reflection manipulations, usually I'm using simple helper class, which extracts MethodInfo from LambdaExpression.
Your code can be simplified via this helper in the following manner:
MethodInfo method = MemberHelper.MethodOfGeneric((AppDbContext ctx) => ctx.Set<object>());

And helper class implementation:
public static class MemberHelper
{
    public static MethodInfo MethodOf<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>>                         methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall);
    public static MethodInfo MethodOf<T1, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, TResult>>                 methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall);
    public static MethodInfo MethodOf<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>>         methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall);
    public static MethodInfo MethodOf<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>> methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall);

    public static MethodInfo MethodOfGeneric<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>>                         methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall).GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    public static MethodInfo MethodOfGeneric<T1, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, TResult>>                 methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall).GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    public static MethodInfo MethodOfGeneric<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>>         methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall).GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    public static MethodInfo MethodOfGeneric<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>> methodCall) => GetMethodInfo(methodCall).GetGenericMethodDefinition();

    static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(LambdaExpression lambda)
    {
        if (GetMemberInfo(lambda) is not MethodInfo methodInfo)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a method call expression.");

        return methodInfo;
    }

    static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(LambdaExpression func)
    {
        return GetMemberInfo(func.Body);
    }

    static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(Expression expr)
    {
        if (expr is MemberExpression memberExpr)
            return memberExpr.Member;

        if (expr is MethodCallExpression methodExpr)
            return methodExpr.Method;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression or a method call expression.");
    }
}

It can be extended to get constructors, properties, etc.

While that works, the question itself is a very strong indication that EF is misused

@PanagiotisKanavos, yes, probably another super repository. Leaving this answer as reference to similar questions.

You need to use an overload of the .GetMethod() where there is an array of Type[] types, and pass an array of length 0 to it.
